# Get min value of multiple columns R

Tags: r, sorting, min

Imagine I have a data frame with two columns A and B (input shown below). What I want is to get the minim value of the combination of the two columns with respect to B. So I order column B and then get the minimum value of A that is also the minimum value in B. Hence I get the output shown below. Hope I explained it clearly. I couldn't find anything related to this.

Input:
A B 
1 0 
0 1 
7 1 
3 2

Desired Output:
A B 
0 1

Comment: Sounds like schoolwork to me.

Answer (score 1):

Use `order` function.

```
df <- data.frame(A=sample(1:5,10,rep=TRUE),B=sample(1:5,10,rep=TRUE))
df
   A B
1  3 4
2  1 2
3  2 3
4  3 2
5  4 2
6  4 2
7  3 1
8  1 4
9  4 1
10 3 1

df[order(df$A,df$B),]
   A B
2  1 2
8  1 4
3  2 3
7  3 1
10 3 1
4  3 2
1  3 4
9  4 1
5  4 2
6  4 2
df[order(df$A,df$B)[1],]
  A B
2 1 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `arrange` from `dplyr`.

```
#df from the post by @bartektartanus
library(dplyr)
df%>%arrange(A,B)%>% head(1)
#  A B
#1 1 2
```